# css absolute positioning reverse

Tags: css

Hi I'm really confuse with the absolute positioning in this tutorial.

I can't understand why by using left: 0 on the figure tag, his actually making a margin left

of 335px, and also why when his using left it's actually acting like right: 0.

I know that this type of problem can occur when the actual parent div is 0 width or 0

height, since his not able to display a block element

Here is part of the css code:

```
.ia-container figure {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50px; /* width of visible piece */
    width: 335px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

You can find the demo here:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/06/06/image-accordion-with-css3/

Comment: If you want help, please construct a working example including all relevant code and a jsFiddle demo.  Don't just dump a link to somebody else's page and ask us to figure it all out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't.

The `left` comes from another rule

```
.ia-container input:checked ~ figure {
    left: 335px;
    transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
```